# C# - Argumented method calling

Tags: c#, .net, performance, events

I've got a class that have 3 methods

1. public DoSth
2. private DoItForReal
3. private DoSthExtra

User can call one of 2 constructors (object can be changed olny during construction)

I want user to call DoSth method and depending on with constructor was called I wand to call:
- DoItForReal (only!)
- DoItForReal and DoSthExtra

My question is wchih implementation is better of performance (DoSth will be called 30 times a sec) ?

Implementation1 (using if statemant):

```
DoSth()
{
    DoItForReal();
    if (ctor1)
        DoSthExtra();
}
```

Implementation2 (using events):

```
private event Action DoSthEvent;
Ctor1()
{
    DoSthEvent += DoItForReal;
    DoSthEvent += DoSthExtra;
}
Ctor2()
{
    DoSthEvent += DoItForReal;
}
DoSth()
{
    DoSthEvent();
}
```

Comment: Try to read it as politely as possible: Can you please find less stupid names?

Comment: My gut tells me events will be slower. You can't get much faster than an `if`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you're running `DoSth()` 30 times / second - does *DoSth* stand for *Denial of Servith*?

Comment: Naming proposal: name the class Pokemon, have the method names be names of attacks, and have the `ctor` flag be `isEvolved`. SO needs more pokemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 times per second is *nothing*. You should *definitely* go with the first solution - it's far clearer what's going on. (Why you'd want to use an *event* for this even in the second case is beyond me... A simple `Action` type variable would be better. It's not like you're really using this like an event.)

I *suspect* the first form is faster as well, but it's not even worth benchmarking - because any difference in speed will be entirely negligible when you're talking about calling it 30 times per second.